# Connect Spring Backend to HTML SearchBar Frontend

Tags: java, html, spring, api, connection

Here's the situation:

I have a Spring Boot project, in which admittedly little is in it so far, because as a rather inexperienced programmer I am already facing a problem at the beginning.

In the backend I have a Spring Boot app with Java, in the frontend simply HTML with a bit of Bootstrap. I don't have a database, but only an API query that a friend provided me with for practice purposes. It looks something like this: https://my-dev.mydomain.de/api/v1/search/je/products?q=productname

[image]

[image]

My first big problem is that I can't get my search field to connect to my backend. As you can see on the picture the app started and can be accessed under localhost. The front end of my search is displayed, but when I enter something it doesn't search the API and doesn't show anything further down the page under "Results"....

Please ignore the "Filter" section. That's where I actually wanted the user to be able to refine their search. But since I can't even manage the basics yet, I'll probably leave that out for now.

I want to do it myself and not be told how to do it, but maybe there is someone here who can explain to me how to establish the connection between the backend and the search field or results list, so that at least they can do something. Maybe he knows some helpful tutorials that I can use on my own. Unfortunately I can only find some where you have a database and repositories in the background. I had that before and it worked. Only now with this API query I somehow don't get along.

I am looking forward to your helpful answers. Thanks in advice.

Comment: You need to include more details to get valuable answers but essentially what you will want to do is provide a POST mapping in your controller that handles the "search".  In this method, use `RestTemplate` to call the API and gather the results.  Add these results to a ModelMap and return a ModelAndView from your controller that contains the view name to render, along with the ModelMap that contains the data from the API call.  This is the gist of what you need to do, you'll want to follow good practices like making the API call in a service that's injected into the controller, etc.

Comment: Do not post images of your code, post the code instead. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks with RestTemplate I did it and it works! Awesome!